# Error installing cocoapods, Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, flutter, cocoapods

I am new here. So I want to install Ruby on my Mac Pro M1, but this error appear. And I don't know how to fix it.

```
Last login: Fri Nov  4 15:37:04 on ttys000
/Users/valerianathea/.zshrc:5: unmatched "
valerianathea@valerianas-MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20221104-41514-zbjk3e.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in `try_link0'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in `try_ldflags'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out
valerianathea@valerianas-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Can someone help me fix this error? I really need help.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have xcode install in your mac? If not, try installing with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Try installing the latest ruby version with Homebrew:

```
brew install ruby
```

Make sure you have Ruby in your PATH:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/xxx/.bash_profile
```

If you have already followed above stepe, Try running the following command:

```
brew cleanup -d -v
```

Then try installing cocoapods with Homebrew:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

If you see failed to link then `run brew link cocoapods`

If linking is getting failed then run

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

If none of the above works, try the following steps:

1. `sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
2. `sudo gem install cocoapods`

If you get any error,then try step 3:

3. `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`